# How to make an overlay of all tags

Tags: awesome-wm

How do I create a global overlay of all tags?

Pressing a shortcut should make all tags appear in seperate boxes in one screen. It should  look something like this: [image: Overlay image]

How can I make something like this? How can I seperate tags in boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [collision](https://github.com/Elv13/collision) module or the [bling](https://blingcorp.github.io/bling/#/widgets/tag_preview) module has something close enough. Getting the exact layout you ask for is non-trivial because AwesomeWM is not a compositing window manager. This means it cannot really take screenshots (let alone live-views) of invisible clients/windows. Usually, the only "safe" thing is to display the outline and client `icon`.

If you really, really want this, you need:

1. A compositing manager such as [picom](https://github.com/yshui/picom/)
2. Either [these patches](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/pull/3461) or use `gears.surface(client.content)` to take a screenshot
3. Lot of code to properly render a wibox with the right screenshots. You can read the bling or collision code to know how to get the size and position.